# What are the main differences between HDFS and Databricks DBFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, databricks

I quite understand each one. But which are the main differences?

Do both persists data on-disk?

What if I mount a non-distributed system to the databricks DBFS?

Answer (score 5):

I think in HDFS the data is persisted on the local servers , but in DBFS they use the S3 as storage , basically taking the storage out of the compute . 
The WASB ( Windows Azure Storage Blob) does the same thing and the take the storage to blobs . Please read [this](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dbfs-databricks-file-system.html) .

This is what it says 
"Databricks File System (DBFS) is a distributed file system installed on Databricks clusters. Files in DBFS persist to S3, so you won’t lose data even after you terminate a cluster."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This give another question. When HDFS persist on local servers, all the data is distributed across these servers. But in DBFS if it persist on Blob Storage, this data isn't distributed anymore right? I understand S3 is distributed so it "emulates" distributed servers, but whith Blob storage isn't the same case.

Comment: I have a similar question. DBFS is a file system and S3 is an object storage. How comes a distributed file system is backed by an object storage system?

Comment: @marz there is no difference between S3 and ABS in the context of Databricks DBFS. "Distributed" means that it can be accessed by multiple cluster nodes. It is fairly close analog of HDFS (if we don't go into details of what is under the hood).

Comment: dbfs is a translation layer that is compatible with spark, enabling it to see a shared filesystem from all nodes. Databricks also has clever caching layers and vectorized IO (see photon) so it's not slow. The object storage will behave very similarly to a distributed filesystem, especially if data is spread over multiple files that can be loaded in parallel to different executors on the cluster nodes (from deltalake, using partitioning, clustering or "liquid clustering").